# How to resolve go build errors for github.com/godror/godror?

Tags: go, x86-64, go-build

On a Mac Os, I'm trying to build the below file to run in a linux machine.

```golang
package main

import (
    "context"
    "database/sql"
    _ "github.com/godror/godror"
)

func main() {
    dsn := "user/password@host:port/sid"

    // Open a connection to the Oracle database
    db, err := sql.Open("godror", dsn)
    if err != nil {
        panic(err.Error())
    }
    defer db.Close()

    // Test the database connection
    ctx := context.Background()
    err = db.PingContext(ctx)
    if err != nil {
        panic(err.Error())
    }

    query := "SELECT * FROM table"
    rows, err := db.QueryContext(ctx, query)
    if err != nil {
        panic(err.Error())
    }
    defer rows.Close()

    if err := rows.Err(); err != nil {
        panic(err.Error())
    }
}
```

I'm using the below command to build:

`env GOOS=linux GOARCH=amd64 go build db.go`

Errors:

```
# github.com/godror/godror
../../../../pkg/mod/github.com/godror/godror@v0.39.2/orahlp.go:530:19: undefined: VersionInfo
../../../../pkg/mod/github.com/godror/godror@v0.39.2/orahlp.go:531:19: undefined: VersionInfo
../../../../pkg/mod/github.com/godror/godror@v0.39.2/orahlp.go:532:10: undefined: StartupMode
../../../../pkg/mod/github.com/godror/godror@v0.39.2/orahlp.go:533:11: undefined: ShutdownMode
../../../../pkg/mod/github.com/godror/godror@v0.39.2/orahlp.go:535:31: undefined: Event
../../../../pkg/mod/github.com/godror/godror@v0.39.2/orahlp.go:535:42: undefined: SubscriptionOption
../../../../pkg/mod/github.com/godror/godror@v0.39.2/orahlp.go:535:64: undefined: Subscription
../../../../pkg/mod/github.com/godror/godror@v0.39.2/orahlp.go:536:31: undefined: ObjectType
../../../../pkg/mod/github.com/godror/godror@v0.39.2/orahlp.go:537:59: undefined: Data
../../../../pkg/mod/github.com/godror/godror@v0.39.2/orahlp.go:538:28: undefined: DirectLob
../../../../pkg/mod/github.com/godror/godror@v0.39.2/orahlp.go:538:28: too many errors
```

I am able to build for Mac OS, but having issues to build for linux. Could you help me resolve these errors?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This cross-compilation error is due to the usage of CGO by the `github.com/godror/godror` package. For compiling the application you need a valid gcc installation and CGO_ENABLED=1, as mentioned in the [readme](https://github.com/godror/godror#:%7E:text=C%20compiler%20with%20CGO_ENABLED%3D1%20%2D%20so%20cross%2Dcompilation%20is%20hard) of the package.
You can try compiling for linux/amd64 using docker.

Example:

```
DOCKER_DEFAULT_PLATFORM=linux/amd64 docker run --rm -v "$PWD":/app -w /app golang:1.21 go build -v db.go
```

This will build the application in a docker container and save the executable in the current directory.

Comment: the binary is throwing the below error: 
./db

./db: /lib64/libc.so.6: version `GLIBC_2.32' not found (required by ./db)
./db: /lib64/libc.so.6: version `GLIBC_2.34' not found (required by ./db)

Comment: Can you provide information about the environment you are trying to run this binary? Which OS/Docker image are you using? Does it have a GC available?

Comment: I'm trying to run the go binary on CentOS Linux, Version 7. GC : gcc (GCC) 4.8.5 20150623 (Red Hat 4.8.5-44)

Comment: You can build binary using centos image, to ensure it looks for gcc related components at correct path.

`DOCKER_DEFAULT_PLATFORM=linux/amd64 docker run -e GOPATH="/go" -e PATH="$GOPATH/bin:/usr/local/go/bin:$PATH" -e CGO_ENABLED=1 --rm -v "$PWD":/app -w /app centos:centos7 sh -c "\
yum -y install wget gcc &&\
wget https://go.dev/dl/go1.21.0.linux-amd64.tar.gz && \
tar -C /usr/local -xzf go*.linux-amd64.tar.gz && go env && \
go build -v db.go"`

This will start a centos container and install gcc & golang required for building the binary

Comment: Thank you for your time and help. However, I'm still getting the below error : `2023-09-06 17:09:03 (8.67 MB/s) - 'go1.21.0.linux-amd64.tar.gz.1' saved [66479500/66479500]

tar: go1.21.0.linux-amd64.tar.gz: Not found in archive
tar: Exiting with failure status due to previous errors`

Could you suggest any resolution to this ?

Comment: I modified the command slightly and I was able to build it. Here is the command: `DOCKER_DEFAULT_PLATFORM=linux/amd64 docker run -e GOPATH="/go" -e PATH="$GOPATH/bin:/usr/local/go/bin:$PATH" -e CGO_ENABLED=1 --rm -v "$PWD":/app -w /app centos:centos7 sh -c 'yum -y install wget gcc && wget https://go.dev/dl/go1.21.0.linux-amd64.tar.gz && tar -C /usr/local -xzf go1.21.0.linux-amd64.tar.gz && /usr/local/go/bin/go env && /usr/local/go/bin/go build -v db.go'` . Thank you.